# If $\int_Df=0$ implies $||\bar g-g||\rightarrow 0$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $D$ be in $\mathbb R^n $. Let $f\in L^2(D)$. I proved that for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists a unique $\bar g\in H^1(D)$ such that $\int_D \nabla \bar g \nabla h+\int_D\epsilon \bar g h=\int_D hf$ for all $h\in H^1(D)$.

There exists a unique $g\in H^1(D)$ such that $\int_Dg=0$ and $\int_D \nabla g \nabla h=\int_D hf$ for all $h\in H^1(D)$ if and only if $\int_Df=0$.

I want to show that if $\int_Df=0$ then $||\bar g-g||$ converges to $0$.

If $\int_D f=0$ then by choosing $h=\bar g -g$ we can write $||\bar g -g||_{H^1(D)}=\int _D(\epsilon \bar gg−ϵ\bar g^2+\bar g^2−2\bar gg+g^2)$. Is there a way to show that the limit of this integral is $0$? Is that even true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* Test your very first variational equation with the constant function $h \equiv 1$.

Comment: Poincaré's inequality yields that $g_\epsilon$ is bounded in $H^1(\Omega)$. Similarly, you get $\int |\nabla (g_\epsilon - g)|^2 \le \epsilon \, \int g_\epsilon \, (g_\epsilon - g)$ and this right-hand side goes to zero. Applying Poincaré again ($g_\epsilon - g$ has zero mean) yields convergence.

Comment: $g $ and $g_\epsilon$ are bounded in $H^1$.

Comment: Put $h = g_\epsilon$ into the weak formulation for $g_\epsilon$. On the right-hand side, you can use Poincaré again. This gives $\|\nabla g_\epsilon\|_2^2 \le \| h \|_2 \, \|g_\epsilon\|_2 \le c \, \|h\|_2 \, \|\nabla g_\epsilon\|_2$.